# No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: android, post, http-post

I am trying to post an image to a REST service using Apache HTTP Post the example I have is.

POST /Example/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.23.1 libcurl/7.23.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
Host: www.******.com/443
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer access token
Content-Length: 32741
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------a24d743fe

I am using the following code.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(str);          
StringEntity se;
try {

httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=---------a24d743fe");
httppost.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.getAccessToken());

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
Log.d("uri",getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
File file= new File(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
if(file.exists())
{
    Log.d("file","exists");
    entity.addPart("image data", new FileBody(file));
}

httppost.setEntity(entity);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = 
(BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);

Log.d("HTTPStatus",httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
```

but I get the following error.

05-01 10:18:31.400: D/response(1872): {"errorCode":600000,"errorType":"service_error","message":"No content to map to Object due to end of input","correlationId":"9331d2343b721"}

I am really stuck and would appreciate any help!!

Comment: try to send the http request through another platform to check if the problem is in the input or in the code. I recommend "Advanced REST Client" for Chrome

Comment: Does the message mean it is receiving an object that it is not expecting or not receiving the full file?

Comment: you get a server response so the problem is not in the connectivity but in the data, it might be in the way you encode it or in the data itself. try to find out where the problem is by sending the request directly through a rest client

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have set "content-length" header.